Block "Check charging accessory" notification completely
I have a Google Pixel 6a with the latest updates. When I charge it, a "Check charging accessory" notification appears.
The cable and power supply are not going to be changing, and the phone charges perfectly fine and exactly as we need it to in its remote location.  It's just the message is flat-out wrong for this use in this location.  It's going to be unattended for weeks at a time, in a very remote monitoring site, with multiple redundant power sources feeding it. If we lost contact with it for 15 minutes, we would know and the message keeps getting in the way.
The reason why it is immaterial and I am not seeking any advice on cables, adapters, reasons why, etc., is because I simply want it gone. I don't want to see the message again.
Any advice on removing it is very welcome.

I would assume that this notification appears because the used charging mode is slower than the maximum supported (e.g. blocked by the USB-C cable). Thus charging works fine just not at maximum speed. As far as I remember there is no "Fast charging" setting in Google devices you could disable (which should prevent this message).
